# How to gganimate a stacked bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to make a transition between four stacked bar graphs. The output is not  quite what I expected and I haven't been able to figure if it's an error in my code or if it's a bug in `gganimate` R package.

This is the data frame I use:

```
df <- structure(list(name = c("variable", "variable", "variable", "variable",    
    "variable", "variable", "variable", "variable", "variable", "variable", 
    "variable", "variable", "variable"), groups = structure(c(3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("group 1", 
    "group 2", "group 3", "group 4"), class = "factor"), score = structure(c(4L, 
    3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("4", 
    "3", "2", "1"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), percentage = c(8, 
    38, 38, 16, 17.1428571428571, 40, 42.8571428571429, 40, 20, 40, 
    5, 65, 30), percentage2 = c("8%", "38%", "38%", "16%", "17.1%", 
    "40%", "42.9%", "40%", "20%", "40%", "5%", "65%", "30%"), label = c(0.04, 
    0.27, 0.65, 0.92, 0.0857142857142857, 0.371428571428571, 0.785714285714286, 
    0.2, 0.5, 0.8, 0.025, 0.375, 0.85)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

When I make a stacked bar graph of just one stage of the groups variable, I get e.g. this:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot(filter(df, groups == "group 3"),
       aes(x = name, y = percentage, fill = score)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", width = 0.8) +
    geom_text(aes(y = label, label = percentage2), color = "grey25") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values=c("darkgreen", "lightgreen", "yellow", "red"), 
                      guide = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE), drop=FALSE)
```

[image]

But When I try to add a `gganimate` animation of the four different group stages I get this:

```
library(gganimate)

ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = percentage, fill = score)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "fill", width = 0.8) + 
    geom_text(aes(y = label, label = percentage2), color = "grey25") +
    coord_flip() +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "lightgreen", "yellow", "red"), 
                      guide= guide_legend(reverse = TRUE), drop = FALSE) + 
    transition_states(groups, transition_length = 2, state_length =  1)
```

[image]

It seems to add all the percentages (bar lengths) of all the groups to the animation at the same time. I want a transition between the stacked bar graphs of the four different groups without the gaps. How can I get this animation to make a transition between the bars without gaps?

Comment: `I think it's obvious this is not what I intended.`  - What did you intend? What is the `right way`?

Comment: @Roman I changed the text a little bit. I hope it's more clear now.

Comment: @Roman, thank you for the editing!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm writing a lengthy response now :-)

Comment: @Roman I am looking forward to it! thomasp85 says it's a bug: https://twitter.com/thomasp85/status/1052142237667270658?s=09

Comment: Possible improvement for your data: add rows with `0` percentage observations so that the animation becomes more smoothly (see `score 1`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 1]

Definitely possible, but in the current version of `gganimate` you need to edit your data frame.

#### Code

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = name, y = c, fill = score, group = score)) +
    geom_col(position = "identity", width = 0.8) +
    coord_flip() +
    labs(title = "{closest_state}") +
    geom_label(aes(y = c, label = percentage2)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "lightgreen", "yellow", "red"), 
                      guide= guide_legend(reverse = TRUE), drop = FALSE) +
    transition_states(groups, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1)
animate(g, nframes = 100)
```

#### Data

```
df$c <- ave(df$percentage, df$group, FUN=cumsum)
df <- df[order(df$groups, df$score, df$c), ]

df
       name  groups score percentage percentage2      label         c
10 variable group 1     4   40.00000         40% 0.80000000 100.00000
9  variable group 1     3   20.00000         20% 0.50000000  60.00000
8  variable group 1     2   40.00000         40% 0.20000000  40.00000
7  variable group 2     4   42.85714       42.9% 0.78571429 100.00000
6  variable group 2     3   40.00000         40% 0.37142857  57.14286
5  variable group 2     2   17.14286       17.1% 0.08571429  17.14286
4  variable group 3     4   16.00000         16% 0.92000000 100.00000
3  variable group 3     3   38.00000         38% 0.65000000  84.00000
2  variable group 3     2   38.00000         38% 0.27000000  46.00000
1  variable group 3     1    8.00000          8% 0.04000000   8.00000
13 variable group 4     4   30.00000         30% 0.85000000 100.00000
12 variable group 4     3   65.00000         65% 0.37500000  70.00000
11 variable group 4     2    5.00000          5% 0.02500000   5.00000
```

========================

#### Explanation

Why? In `gganimate` version `"0.9.9.9999"` the animated plot will not group & stack correctly (a bug, as you pointed out correctly). This is why you need to

1. Feature engineer the position of the bar (variable `c`)
2. Order the bars by descending size of `c` (so that the bigger ones don't overlap the smaller ones)

What was really helpful: to break down the code to the bare bones and just keep the important stuff:

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = "", y = c, fill = score, group = score)) +
    geom_col(position = "identity") +
    labs(title = "{closest_state}") +
    transition_states(groups, transition_length = 2, state_length = 1)
    animate(g, nframes = 10)
```

This was much easier to work with than the original code. There it became clear that the problem lies somewhere in the interplay of `y =` (e.g., c, percentage), `group =` (e.g., score, groups), and `position =` (e.g., stack, dodge, dodge2, identity, fill).

If you have any questions please do not hesitate to shoot me a message.