# gganimate a stacked bar chart per bar color

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I've seen [the same question but without a working solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54045103/gganimate-stacked-bar-chart-over-time). And [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830938/how-to-gganimate-a-stacked-bar-graph) looks the same at first but doesn't really cover my question.

I would like to first plot and animate the bottom purple bars, then the light blue ones on top for the finishing stacked result and then loop. How can this be done with the `gganimate` package.

First my animated bar chart with the stacks per year at the same time.

[image]

Here's my the data:

```
example_df <- structure(list(jaar = c(2019, 2019, 2018, 2018, 2017, 2017, 2016, 
2016, 2015, 2015, 2014, 2014, 2013, 2013, 2012, 2012, 2011, 2011, 
2010, 2010), type = c("purple", "blue", "purple", "blue", "purple", 
"blue", "purple", "blue", "purple", "blue", "purple", "blue", 
"purple", "blue", "purple", "blue", "purple", "blue", "purple", 
"blue"), aantal = c(322L, 338L, 328L, 354L, 303L, 302L, 257L, 
245L, 223L, 185L, 183L, 128L, 141L, 80L, 121L, 58L, 104L, 46L, 
94L, 38L)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Here's my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)

anim_bar <- example_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(jaar, aantal)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = type)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1beaae", "#6b38e8")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  transition_time(jaar) +
  shadow_mark() +
  enter_grow() +
  enter_fade()

animate(anim_bar, fps = 20)
```

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this? It seems like it would be pretty difficult to "read" the chart

Comment: I editted my question by clarifying my desired result question. Through animation I want to clarify the growing trend and the massive share light blue plays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach using some manipulation beforehand to specify the order of appearance and what each bar should look like when it appears. I had more luck by precalculating the stacking location and specifying the coordinates with `geom_tile`.

```
example_df %>%
  arrange(desc(type), jaar) %>%
  mutate(frame_num = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(jaar) %>%
  mutate(space_below = cumsum(lag(aantal, default = 0))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%

  ggplot() +
  geom_tile(aes(jaar, space_below + aantal/2, 
                width = 0.9, height = aantal,
                fill = type)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#1beaae", "#6b38e8")) +
  theme(legend.position = "top") +
  transition_time(frame_num) +
  shadow_mark() +
  enter_grow() +
  enter_fade() ->   anim_bar

animate(anim_bar, fps = 20)
```

[image]